# Simultaneously displaying and capturing standard out in IPython?

Tags: ipython

I'm interested in implementing a behavior in IPython that would be like a combination of `!` and `!!`.  I'm trying to use an IPython terminal as an adjunct to my (Windows) shell.  For a long running command (e.g., a build script) I would like to be able to watch the output as it streams by as `!` does.  I would also like to capture the output of the command into the output history as `!!` does, but this defers printing anything until all output is available.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how to implement something like this?  I'm guessing that a `IPython.utils.io.Tee()` object would be useful here, but I don't know enough about IPython to hook this up properly.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a snippet of code I just tried in iPython notebook v2.3, which seems to do what was requested:

```
import sys
import IPython.utils.io
outputstream = IPython.utils.io.Tee("outputfile.log", "w", channel="stdout")
outputstream.write("Hello worlds!\n")
outputstream.close()

logstream=open("outputfile.log", "r")
sys.stdout.write("Read back from log file:\n")
sys.stdout.write(logstream.read())
```

The log file is created in the same directory as the iPython notebook file, and the output from running this cell is displayed thus:

```
Hello worlds!
Read back from log file:
Hello worlds!
```

I haven't tried this in the iPython terminal, but see no reason it wouldn't work as well there.

*(Researched and answered as part of the Oxford participation in http://aaronswartzhackathon.org)*